# Can SerialPort.Close raise an exception?

Tags: c#, wpf, serial-port

Is it possible that Close function of SerialPort raises an Exception. How to safely close serial port?

```
        try
        {

            serial.Open();
            serial.DataReceived += ReceiveHex;

            // do sth

            return true;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            // is it possible that Exception is raised here? 
            serial.DataReceived -= ReceiveHex;
            serial.Close();  
        }
```

Comment: Every .NET Framework method can throw an exception.  Fretting about it is pretty pointless, something is seriously wrong so you *want* to know when it does.  Leaving the program running is a very bad idea.  Exceptions are your friend, never, *never* swallow them.  So `return false;` is already a drastically bad idea, your program won't work and there is no possible way for the user to find out why or what he could do to fix the problem.  You'll get a support phone call that you cannot answer.

Comment: What if the serial port failed to open and you still called close. I believe it will cause an exception. In example, no device is connected to the port you tried to connect to..

Answer (score 0):

Yes SerialPort.Close() can throw an IOException. Look the documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.ports.serialport.close%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

But I never had something like this. I think your code is safe.